# Emacs isn't working with this key sequence?

Tags: emacs, key-bindings, mintty

I'm trying to bind backwards-kill-line to Ctrl-Backspace. The following binds work:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-\d") 'backward-kill-line) ; emacs-w32
(global-set-key (kbd "\b") 'backward-kill-line) ; xterm
```

However, when I log into ssh from Windows I generally use Mintty. The Ctrl-v sequence reported by Bash is '\037' but this isn't recognized by emacs. Instead, every time I press Ctrl-Backspace while emacs running on the Mintty term, the following characters are sent to the buffer: ';5u'.

Is there a way to tell emacs to use ';5u' as the key binding? Specifying (kbd ";5u") won't work because emacs expects a single character.

Comment: You are not seeing the full picture. \037 is esc and the sequence is probably esc [ ; 5 u or something like that. But you should not be mapping raw terminal sequences; you should set things up so that your terminal program is communicating properly with the server (probably your `TERM` variable is wrong, but there are many moving parts).

Comment: Mintty has its own custom terminal sequences like many other terminals. All I need is to figure out what they are for this sequence.

Comment: The [documentation](https://code.google.com/p/mintty/) says `xterm`-compatible.  Did you try with `TERM=xterm`?

Comment: Upon further digging it seems that enabling the option "Backspace sends ^H" in the Mintty->Options->Keys dialog provides the correct mapping for xterm. However, I still get ';5u' when I press Ctrl-Backspace in emacs?

Answer (score -1):

Make Emacs do help for you, type `C-h k` and your `C-v`, Emacs shown  something like I get for `Ctrl + numPlus` when do this in `xterm`:

```
M-O 5 k is undefined
```

which I translate into

```
 (global-set-key (kbd "M-O 5 k") 'end-of-line)
```

and that work fine!

**UPDATE** Use my `expect` script to get byte sequence from terminal you get when press key combination: http://sourceforge.net/u/gavenkoa/utils/ci/default/tree/misc/keyseq.exp

If you use `mintty` I check docs: https://code.google.com/p/mintty/wiki/Tips and your key code sequence is very similar to another examples so I believe that:

```
 (global-set-key (kbd "\e[1;5u") 'end-of-line)
```

do job for you.

Check topics from `(info "(elisp)Reading Input)`.

**UPDATE 2** You are trapped into `Ctrl+Backspace` issue for terminals, investigate info yourself: https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=ctrl+backspace+terminal

I remember that I have same issue few years ago. Main problem that `Ctrl+Backspace` generate same byte sequence in terminal emulators as `Ctrl-H`. For that reason I train to use `ESC Backspace` for deleting word backward. I never deep into terminal emulation standarts and implementation code to understand if it possible to generate different code sequence in `mintty` for `C-Backspace` ((

Comment: I'm trying to get the right sequence for Mintty not xterm. `C-h k` doesn't work for the Ctrl-Backspace sequence I want.

Comment: The output of you script for Ctrl-Backspace is: `(ASCII octal 0177, decimal 127, hexadecimal 7f)`. I'm not sure what to do with that. Also, neither '\e[1;5u' or '\e[0;5u' works; this is the first thing I tried.

Comment: It's  a `?\x7f` or same as `?\C-?`, so `(kbd "\x7f")` or  `(kbd "\C-?")`

Comment: Oh, I remember that I have same issue few years ago. Main problem that `Ctrl+Backspace` generate same byte sequence in terminal emulators as `Ctrl-H`. For that reason I train to use `ESC Backspace` for deleting word backward. I never deep into terminal emulation standarts and implementation code to understand if it possible to generate different code sequence in `mintty`for `C-Backspace` ((

Comment: That's why default Mintty sends `^_` instead of `^H` like xterm.